# Make an element within sortable scroll its parent instead of the whole page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having a [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) element defined this way:

```
<div class="list first">
  <div class="sortable">
    <div class="draggable">A</div>
    <div class="draggable">B</div>
    <div class="draggable">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list second>...</div>
```

And then there's a sortable setting:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  helper: 'clone',
  items: '.draggable',
  containment: 'document',
  scroll: true,
  connectWith: '.list',
  appendTo: document.body
});
```

The problem is that when I drag an element, it doesn't scroll its `.sortable` parent. So if I want to move an element from top of the list to its bottom, I can't do it in a single movement.

Is it a technical limitation, or does this problem already have a solution?

Comment: do you have a fiddle so we can see the issue?